# Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory AcquireTokenAsync always requires a resource when the documentation says it doesnt

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have a requirement that I use Azure AD to authenticate my clinet applications using OAuth 2.0.

We started using the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenAsync library but you MUST pass a resource:
[image]

Even though the documentation here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/

Says it's optional:
[image]

We don't want to pass a **resource** as our clients should know as a little as possible about the back-end services so changes in the future are minimal.

Another requirement is that we use the app-only flow so we dont need any user interaction.

I have tried writing straight HTTP rest calls using RestSharp but I can't get around the popup.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to pass a resource anyway but on the server end we just force the validation to return true no matter what resource URL is passed:

```
TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
AudienceValidator = AudienceValidator,
},
private bool AudienceValidator(IEnumerable<string> audiences, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
{
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is related to version of DDL, previously i am facing same issue then i have replace my ddl to below version

**Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll--> v2.23.0.0**

now it work for me.

you can download here

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/2.23.302261847

Comment: can you give me more information? I am currently on version 3.12.0 of the DLL. Why would I want to go back to 2.23.0.0. Also, the resource is still mandatory

Comment: i am not sure but i think they have change entire architecture of identity model.